# Button specific to slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making portfolio site, where I have a slider for each project and inside it there is second slider for different images.

Sliders working fine but can't make the button "`myBabel`" disappear when viewing "`myBerlin`".

Also, I can't add second button to make the "myBerlin" slider work.

I want to add one button that either controls all the inside sliders (the slidshow that contains are controlled by left and right screen buttons) by one button in the middle or one button per inside slider that moves with it.

I tried adding "`myBerlin`" to the `onclick="myBabel();`..." but then my sliderscript doesn't work anymore and skips most of my images. I also tried adding the button in the slider itself but doesn't work.

Anyone has a solution? I tried different solutions already.

https://jsfiddle.net/r87dc1j5/

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code

Comment: make a jsfiddle and keep the whole code there(and share the link here) and give only the part you want help about. that will give you a quick answer to your question. :)

Comment: I added a smaller version of my code on jsfiddle and added some more information!

Comment: Can you please add a minimal and self-verifiable code, as stack snippet here with your question.